# Set network IP address using ManagementObject class in WPF?

Tags: wpf, winforms, ip-address

I am trying to change IP address of local machine using **ManagementObject** class (.net 3.5) in wpf application.

I have used following tried and tested code as available in all forums. 
It changes IP successfully in winform application but it does not work in WPF desktop application.

Is there any restriction in WPF or any other way to do ?

```
internal static void SetNetworkAdaptorIP(string IpAddress, string subnetMask, string gateway)
{
          ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
          ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

            foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
            {

                if (!(bool)objMO["IPEnabled"])
                    continue;

                try
                {
                    ManagementBaseObject objNewIP = null;
                    ManagementBaseObject objSetIP = null;
                    ManagementBaseObject objNewGate = null;

                    objNewIP = objMO.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");
                    objNewGate = objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways");

                    //Set DefaultGateway

                    objNewGate["DefaultIPGateway"] = new string[] { this.txtGateway.Text };
                    objNewGate["GatewayCostMetric"] = new int[] { 1 };


                    //Set IPAddress and Subnet Mask

                    objNewIP["IPAddress"] = new string[] { this.txtIP.Text };
                    objNewIP["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { this.txtSubnet.Text };

                    objSetIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", objNewIP, null);
                    objSetIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", objNewGate, null);


                    MessageBox.Show("Updated IPAddress, SubnetMask and Default Gateway!");

                    return;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unable to Set IP : " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Could you please define 'does not work'? Does it crash, does it burn, does it explode?

Comment: It does not crash. It executes whole code but no change in IP address.